# php stripe checkout showing unexpected error

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to develop a custom-flow stripe payment system. For some reason, its showing 'an unexpected error occurred'. I have checked the console and found this statement - 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_3NYewMIDgqJGqr0P0FchFIQW/confirm 400'

Please note, I am not requesting anyone to write me the code, if possible just guide me where I am getting wrong and indication on how to solve it. I really appreciate your help
Here is my code:

```
create.php

**require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'secrets.php';
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripeSecretKey);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
try {
    // retrieve JSON from POST body
    $jsonStr = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr);
    // Create a PaymentIntent with amount and currency
    $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
        'amount' => 50,
        'currency' => 'gbp',
        'automatic_payment_methods' => [
            'enabled' => true,
        ],
       
    ]);
    $output = [
        'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
    ];
    echo json_encode($output);
} catch (Error $e) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}**
 

checkout.js

// This is your test publishable API key.
const stripe = Stripe("pk_live_...................");

// The items the customer wants to buy
const items = [{ id: "xl-tshirt" }];

let elements;

initialize();
checkStatus();

document
  .querySelector("#payment-form")
  .addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

let emailAddress = '';
// Fetches a payment intent and captures the client secret
async function initialize() {
  const { clientSecret } = await fetch("/create.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ items }),
  }).then((r) => r.json());

  elements = stripe.elements({ clientSecret });

  const linkAuthenticationElement = elements.create("linkAuthentication");
  linkAuthenticationElement.mount("#link-authentication-element");

  const paymentElementOptions = {
    layout: "tabs",
  };

  const paymentElement = elements.create("payment", paymentElementOptions);
  paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");
}

async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setLoading(true);

  const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
      // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
      return_url: "/success.php",
    //   receipt_email: emailAddress,
    },
  });

  
  if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
    showMessage(error.message);
  } else {
    showMessage("An unexpected error occurred.");
  }

  setLoading(false);
}

// Fetches the payment intent status after payment submission
async function checkStatus() {
  const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
    "payment_intent_client_secret"
  );

  if (!clientSecret) {
    return;
  }

  const { paymentIntent } = await stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret);

  switch (paymentIntent.status) {
    case "succeeded":
      showMessage("Payment succeeded!");
      break;
    case "processing":
      showMessage("Your payment is processing.");
      break;
    case "requires_payment_method":
      showMessage("Your payment was not successful, please try again.");
      break;
    default:
      showMessage("Something went wrong.");
      break;
  }
}

// ------- UI helpers -------

function showMessage(messageText) {
  const messageContainer = document.querySelector("#payment-message");

  messageContainer.classList.remove("hidden");
  messageContainer.textContent = messageText;

  setTimeout(function () {
    messageContainer.classList.add("hidden");
    messageContainer.textContent = "";
  }, 4000);
}

// Show a spinner on payment submission
function setLoading(isLoading) {
  if (isLoading) {
    // Disable the button and show a spinner
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `stripe.confirmPayment` function, the `return_url` is not in correct format. The URL should be `https://...` instead of just a path.

Comment: great. tried your solution and it works now. can't thank you enough